# Perl: Adding an exception to a foreach loop

Tags: loops, perl, foreach, line-breaks

I'm new to Stack Overflow and I would like to ask for some advice with regard to a minor problem I have with my Perl code. 
In short, I have written a small programme that opens text files from a pre-defined array, then searches for certain strings in them and finally prints out the line containing the string.

```
my @S1A_SING_Files = (
    'S1A-001_SING_annotated.txt', 
    'S1A-002_SING_annotated.txt',
    'S1A-003_SING_annotated.txt', 
    'S1A-004_SING_annotated.txt',
    'S1A-005_SING_annotated.txt'
    );

foreach (@S1A_SING_Files) {
    print ("\n");
    print ("Search results for $_:\n\n");   
    open (F, $_) or die("Can't open file!\n");

        while ($line = <F>) {
        if ($line =~ /\$(voc)?[R|L]D|\$Rep|\/\//) {
        print ($line);

        }
    }
}

close (F);
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to create an exception to the foreach loop, so that the line containing

```
print ("\n");
```

not be executed if the file is $S1A_SING_Files[0]. It should then be normally executed if the file is any of the following ones. Do you think this could be accomplished?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Just add a check for the first file.  Change:

```
print ("\n");
```

to:

```
print ("\n") if $_ ne $S1A_SING_Files[0];
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the array can contain duplicates values, but `if \$_ != \$S1A_SING_Files[0]` does. Faster, too :)

Answer (score 1):

If the array contains unique strings, you can use the following:

```
print("\n") if $_ ne $S1A_SING_Files[0];     # Different stringification than 1st element?
```

The following will work even if the array contains non-strings or duplicate values (and it's faster too):

```
print("\n") if \$_ != \$S1A_SING_Files[0];   # Different scalar than 1st element?
```

Both of the above could fail for magical arrays. The most reliable solution is to iterate over the indexes.

```
for my $i (0..$#S1A_SING_Files) {
   my $file = $S1A_SING_Files[$i];

   print("\n") if $i;                        # Different index than 1st element?

   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code can be written in following form

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @S1A_SING_Files = (
    'S1A-001_SING_annotated.txt', 
    'S1A-002_SING_annotated.txt',
    'S1A-003_SING_annotated.txt', 
    'S1A-004_SING_annotated.txt',
    'S1A-005_SING_annotated.txt'
    );

foreach (@S1A_SING_Files) {
    print "\n" unless $_ ne $S1A_SING_Files[0];
    print "Search results for $_:\n\n";
    open my $fh, '<', $_ or die("Can't open file!\n");
    m!\$(voc)?[R|L]D|\$Rep|//! && print while <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}
```